# how to give justification in write method in fpdf in python

Tags: python

This is my sample input:

```
s='magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Pellentesque vitae erat. Vivamus porttitor cursus lacus. Pellentesque tellus. Nunc aliquam interdum felis. Nulla imperdiet leo. Mauris hendrerit, sem at mollis pharetra, leo sapien pretium elit, a faucibus sapien dolor vel pede. Vestibulum et enim ut nulla sollicitudin adipiscing. Suspendisse malesuada venenatis mauris. Curabitur ornare mollis velit'

pdf.write(10, s)
```

Justification is not working in write method. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

See the fpdf [script24](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script24.php) on fpdf internet site. It provides a new Justify method and an example on how to use it so as to « justify text by extending the space between letters and not words. This produces homogen paragraphs, without the spaces usually found when justifying »

Comment: this fpdf script24  in php,but need a python code for that